# Azure functions 401 Unauthorized issue with RestSharp

Tags: c#, azure-functions, restsharp

I have been using two different Azure functions to talk to each other, one is an HttpTrigger contained in one app service and another is a TimerTrigger contained in another app service. The HttpTrigger uses Function-level authentication.

Here is my HttpTrigger function:

```
    [FunctionName("PendingOrders")]
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetPendingOrderIds(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route =  "pending-orders")]
        HttpRequestMessage req,
        TraceWriter log,
        [Inject] OrdersController controller)
    {
```

Calling it with the master key works in a browser, but not with RestSharp. The only thing I changed since the previous deployment was upgrading RestSharp from 106.3.1 to 106.6.9. Not a major-version change so there shouldn't be any breaking changes.

```
    private static IRestResponse ProcessRequest(string url, Method method,  object requestBody)
    {
        // Variable "url" is the path plus `?code=<master key here>
        var client = PrepareRequest(url, method, requestBody); // see below
        return client.Execute(); // executes here, returns 401 Unauthorized.
    }

    private static PreparedClient PrepareRequest(string url, Method method,  object requestBody)
    {
        var uri = new Uri(url);
        var client = new RestClient(uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority));
        var request = new RestRequest(uri.PathAndQuery, method)
        {
            OnBeforeDeserialization = resp =>
            {
                resp.ContentType = "application/json";
            }
        };
        if (requestBody != null)
        {
            request.AddJsonBody(requestBody);
        }
        return PreparedClient.Prepare(client, request);
    }
```

Where PreparedClient is

```
internal struct PreparedClient
{
    public IRestClient Client { get; private set; }
    public IRestRequest Request { get; private set; }
    public static PreparedClient Prepare(IRestClient client, IRestRequest  request)
    {
        var prepared = new PreparedClient { Client = client, Request =  request };
        return prepared;
    }
    public IRestResponse Execute()
    {
        return Client.Execute(Request);
    }
    public async Task<IRestResponse> ExecuteAsync()
    {
        return await Client.ExecuteTaskAsync(Request);
    }
}
```

I have debugged the code and verified that the `?code=xxx` master key is being added to the url. Is there a different way of authenticating that I need to use that changed between RestSharp 106.3.1 and 106.6.9? Does something have to be put in the headers?

Comment: please first confirm that you are able to create a request to your function via postman, and show us that it works

Comment: It works with 106.3.1 but not 106.6.9.

Comment: unless you show us that you're able to use postman to create the request, nobody will have enough information to be able to help you here

Comment: I agree that it would be really helpful if you can trace the call in both versions. Indeed there should not be any breaking changes, but we are getting some PRs merged and there's no 100% guarantee that absolutely everything stays the same...